# is it possible to create tabbar application like iphone in black berry

Tags: blackberry, uitabbar

It is possible to create a tabbar for application like iphone in black berry

Answer (score 1):

You can check the link it may help you
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276

you can download the zip file  Advanced UI.zip from the link and The class "Pill Button set" may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a ready-to-use controller, but I think it would be possible to create it.
The Torch device uses such controller for its main menu.